# TCP client stops sending even if window is still open

Tags: tcp

I have a server (developed in house on embedded hardware, the TCP stack is also developed in house) which uses FTP as well as a custom protocol based on TCP to send and receive files,
the client is a Python script running on Windows 10,
there's a weird behavior of the client when sending files that I cannot explain.

Sometimes the server's window almost fills up, at that point the client stops sending
for 5 seconds, I would expect the client to fill the whole window and then eventually
send window probes.

Here's the wireshark capture (captured on a mirrored switch port), I'm not sure why there are missing segments in the capture, might be the switch that does a poor job.

[image: Wireshark capture]

Black frames: client -> server

Green frames: server -> client

It can be seen that frame 557 is sent after a delay of five seconds.

This happens 5 to 10 times during a transfer of a file of 1MB,
I can reproduce this with FTP and our custom protocol.

A working solution would be to send an ack segment as soon as the window opens up more
(in this case a couple of milliseconds after frame 136)

I have no idea why the client waits for 5 seconds instead of just filling up the window,
any ideas?

I Tried to make the server send an ACK after two full segments received (like stated by Jim D.), nothing changes

EDIT:

I learned about the silly window syndrom (SWS) and how to avoid it, the sender and the receiver must implement sws avoidance

Receiver:

As stated [here](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPSillyWindowSyndromeandChangesTotheSlidingWindow-3.htm), the receiver should not advertise a window size smaller than `min(bufsize/2, MSS)`, instead it should say win=0.
This is clearly not the case here as the server advertises win=648

Sender:

As stated [Here](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPSillyWindowSyndromeandChangesTotheSlidingWindow-4.htm), use Nagle's algorithm. We are not using it on the client side, furthermore, after frame 556 all data has been acknowleged, so even according to Nagle's we could send a small segment.

I came accross [This old MS Windows issue](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2861819/data-transfer-stops-for-five-seconds-in-a-windows-socket-based-applica) which talks about a SWS avoidance timer, could it be that the client has such a timer in case the server does not follow the above rule?

In the end, a working solution (and a very easy to implement in our TCP stack) is to send windows updates. A better solution would be to say win=0 when the window is small.

Any thoughts?

EDIT, SOLUTION:

I solved the issue by modifing the TCP stack as follows:

- Advertize a window size = 0 when it is smaller than the MSS
- As soon as the window size grows bigger than (or eq. to) the MSS, advertize the new window size

this gives:
[image: Wireshark capture with fix]

I did not implement the "send ACK after two full segments received", will keep that in mind for the future.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you increase `SO_RCVBUF` on the server socket to something much higher?

Comment: Maybe try setting TCP_NODELAY.  While Nagle's algorithm shouldn't cause the delay shown in the capture, it is nevertheless is a feature that inhibits sending less than a full frame.

Comment: Also, the times in the capture are strange.  It sends 22 1514 byte frames = 266Kb at the same us.  This requires 266us on a gbit nic.  I'm guessing you are capturing on the windows client with a low resolution clock.  Might be helpful to capture what is actually happening on the network.

Comment: Further, you would expect to see an Ack for every 2 full frame packets sent.  Where are the missing Acks?  Oddly configured embedded TCP/IP stack?  Packet loss? Incomplete capture?

Comment: No difference with TCP_NODELAY on client side. Yes, I captured it on the Windows client, I can do a capture later from a mirrored switch port. What do you mean "expect an ACK for every 2 full frame packets sent"? Every second frame should be ACKed? The current ACK behavior is due to the TCP stack configuration/implementation. The implementation roughly says: send ACK after 5 ms of last received data but maximum after 21 segments (the buffer is 32KB, that is, 21 is the amount of segments we can put into buffer minus 1, I'll try to reduce this number)

Comment: So far as I know it is not required by any RFC, but TCP "should" ack every second packet.  See, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_delayed_acknowledgment.  I'm guessing you are seeing some odd interaction with the Windows TCP stack (which I'm not super familiar with) and the odd configuration of the embedded stack.  I'd suggest changing the max from 21 to 2 to behave like an "ordinary" TCP stack if only to see how it affects performance.  Even if you didn't have the 5s issue, the 21 config will have performance problems over a high latency link.

Comment: I made a capture on a mirrored port on a switch, I updated the post.
I tried to make the server send ACK after two received segments (a hack in the code just to try), but nothing changes

Comment: @Pedru but the capture shows that it does not actually ACK every other segment.

Comment: I posted the capture without the "ack every two" modification. the result is the same

Comment: I posted my solution above, thanks for the help